# Stop Jira CSV import from emailing assigned users

Tags: jira

I'm doing a Jira epic/story import using CSV files and mapping the Assignee and Reporter during the import process. During this process however Jira is emailing the users when they get a new assigned item. These are just test loads to ensure data accuracy so I don't want them emailed and hassled during the testing process. I searched my options and tried the Jira FAQs but couldn't find and answer.

Anyone know how to disable this option temporarily?

Thanks in advance!

Tried searching through all Jira system settings but didn't find an option to disable emails during imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is annoying. If all the new issues are in just a few projects, you can remove the project's Notification Schemes before the import, and then restore them after the import is completed. Or change the notification schemes themselves, temporarily

Comment: This is a great idea! I made a "no notifications" scheme which does nothing and applied it. No more messages being sent. Thank you!